# Free Mass Effect 2 DLC?

Tags: ps3, mass-effect-2

When I purchased Mass Effect 2 for the PS3 brand new, I entered the Cerberus Network code and got all the DLC that comes with it.

I played through the game once maybe, then decided to start a new game.

When I started the new game, I went through the comic book story at the beginning that allows you to make choices from the first game. This did not happen the first time I played the game.

I also ended up having the Lair of the Shadow Broker, and the Hammerhead missions as well.

I did not purchase these and as far as I understand, they are not included in the Cerberus Network DLC.

Any idea how this could have happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PlayStation 3 version of Mass Effect 2 was released about a year after it was released for the PC and Xbox 360, and it included all DLC that was released up to that point. This includes Lair of the Shadow Broker.

See [Mass Effect 2 DLC](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Downloadable_Content#General_Content) on the Mass Effect Wiki for a list of all the DLC that is included with the PlayStation 3 version of Mass Effect 2.

Answer (score 2):

Addendom to @Adeese's answer, to address the "comic book story" issue:

I believe the "comic book story" you're referring to is [Mass Effect: Genesis](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect:_Genesis).  This is a free DLC for PS3 players, since the original Mass Effect was not available on that platform when Mass Effect 2 was initially released.

The purpose of this interactive introduction to Mass Effect 2 is to fill in some of the story a player might have missed from the original Mass Effect, and allow them to make critical decisions that *would* have been made during the first game and *will* have an effect on the world in the second.  This was a good thing to have at the time for players who chose to migrate from the Xbox for the series' second installment, and was absolutely essential for PS3-only players.  The Mass Effect series, as I'm sure you recognize, is *very* story-heavy and player decisions play an extremely important part throughout the whole trilogy.

If you imported a save game from Mass Effect, the first time you played Mass Effect 2, then there would have been no need to run Genesis.  The fact that you had a save game to import implies that you've played Mass Effect (1), and thereby know the history, and the import itself handles configuration of all the critical decision points from the first game.  But for the second time around, when you started a new game without an imported character, going through Genesis was necessary for you to fill in (and, the game presumes, for you to learn) Shepard's back-story up to that point.

Answer (score 0):

The Mass Effect series started on Xbox so when it got on PS3, they gave us three free DLCs, Project Overlord, Kasumi Goto, and Lair of the Shadow Broker are included with the disc or download version of the game. For free is Project Firewalker, Zaeed Massani, and others that are in the Cerberus Network pack.